# How to test for closeness in angular quantities

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to write a unit test where the result should be an array of arrays of zero degrees. Using `np.assert_allclose` results in the following failure:

```
E                   AssertionError: 
E                   Not equal to tolerance rtol=1e-07, atol=0.000277778
E                   
E                   (mismatch 100.0%)
E                    x: array([[  3.600000e+02],
E                          [  3.155310e-10]])
E                    y: array([[0],
E                          [0]])
```

What's clearly happening is that the code is working ( `[[360], [3e-10]]` is close enough to `[[0], [0]]` for an angular quantities for me), but `np.assert_allclose` doesn't realize that 0 ≅ 360.

Is there a way to use numpy's testing framework for comparisons where I don't care if the values are off by multiples of 360?

In this particular case, printing the first element of the array with `np.set_printoptions(precision=30)` gives me `359.999999999823955931788077577949`, so this isn't a case that can just be normalized to be between 0 and 360.

This is not a package I maintain, so I'd like to not include other dependencies besides astropy and numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(edited answer, previous version was wrong)

Use e.g. this to reduce your values to the required range:

```
>>> def _h(x, a):
...    xx = np.mod(x, a)
...    return np.minimum(xx, np.abs(a - xx))
```

Then

```
>>> xx = np.asarray([1, -1, 359, 361, 360*3+1, -8*360 + 2])
>>> _h(xx, 360)
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2])
```

Comment: Doesn't work when the value is very close to 360 but just under. I removed the unit-testing tag, although I don't see any guideline for when to use it

Answer (score 1):

Given that all the numbers you want to test for closeness on a circle are in a `ndarray` named `a`, then

```
np.allclose(np.fmod(a+180, 360)-180,0, atol=mytol)
```

or, even simpler,

```
np.allclose(np.fmod(a+180, 360),180, atol=mytol)
```

is all you need (note that `180` is quite arbitrary indeed, it's just that you have to move the comparison away from `0` aka `360`)

**Edit**

I had deleted my answer because of a flaw, that was shown to me in a comment by [ev-br](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143765/ev-br), but later I changed my mind because (thank you ev-br) I saw the light.

One wants to test if a point on a circle, identified by an angle in degrees, is close to the point identified by the angle `0`.  First, the distance on the circumference `D(0,theta)` is equal to `D(0,-theta)`, hence we can compare the absolute values of the angles.

The test I proposed above is valid, or at least I think so, for any positive value of `theta`.

If I use the above test on the absolute values of the angles to be tested, everything 
should be ok, shouldn't it? Here follows a bit of testing

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([0, 1e-5,-1e-7,360.1,-360.1,359.9,-359.9,3600.1,-3600.1,3599.9,-3599.9])

In [3]: np.allclose(np.mod(np.abs(a)+180, 360), 180, atol=0.2)
Out[3]: True

In [4]:
```

Comment: try `np.fmod(-359 + 180, 360)`

Comment: @ev-br As you can see, I've changed my mind. Thank you for your comment, it was enlightening. Thank you very much.